# model is not returning 'rect' 'h' and 'x'

Tags: flutter, object-detection, tflite, boundbox

I am creating an app that will detect objects and bound the object with the box , but i am getting error while using the given code

Error:
Bad field or Empty field ['rect']['h'] call on null

Code:

```
objectDetector(CameraImage image) async {
    var detector = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
      bytesList: image.planes.map((e) {
        return e.bytes;
      }).toList(),
      asynch: true,
      imageHeight: image.height,
      imageWidth: image.width,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
      threshold: 0.4,
    );

     if (detector != null) {
       log("Result is $detector");
       log(detector.first['rect']['h']);
     print(detector!.first['confidence']);

      if(detector.first['confidence'] * 100>45) {
        log("Result$detector");
        label = ourDetectedObject['label'].toString();
         h = ourDetectedObject['rect']['h'];
         w = ourDetectedObject['rect']['w'];
         x = ourDetectedObject['rect']['x'];
        y = ourDetectedObject['rect']['y'];
       }
      print(ourDetectedObject);
       }
update();
    }
```

I want bound boxes around the objects but i am getting error while getting the rect var